# setDropDownBackgroundResource not working in marshmallows android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow

i have try to set the dropdown color for the autocomplete text view it works fine in all other api but when ever i run it with the nexus 5 marshmallows i got the following error

my log cat is

```
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime: Process: test.text.com, PID: 29058
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(int)' on a null object reference
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.java:96)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at test.text.com.activity.CreateRideActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(CreateRideActivity.java:369)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:114)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:114)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:3237)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:9528)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:1200)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3378)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-02 17:36:23.815 29058-29058/test.text.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My code is

```
AutoSuggestView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_rectangle_white_curve_border_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your appcompat libraries. In the current (23.1.1) version of appcompat-v7 the code in `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` was changed to resolve this like so

```
 public void setDropDownBackgroundResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        if (mTintManager != null) {
            setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(mTintManager.getDrawable(resId));
        } else {
            super.setDropDownBackgroundResource(resId);
        }
    }
```